# Maintaining different live versions of the cloud application

Tags: web-applications, versioning, release-management, azure, cloud

I have Microsoft Azure Cloud Application built with App Service. It is supposed to be always "up" for its consumers. When we need to do upgrade and we still need to keep the older one active for sometime till its consumers need (max 1 month). Any other consumer will always use the latest version of the application while still keeping the older versions "up" for older consumers.

How I am planning to do this is like -
say our domain is test.com then

```
test.com/v1 will always redirect to app service v1
test.com/v2 will always redirect to app service v2
test.com/v3 will always redirect to app service v3
```

and so on...
According to business requirement there will be to at most 2 app services 
"up" at a time.

Is this right approach ? Is there any other way to solve this ?

Comment: What is v3 for?

Comment: It was an example..